# autorecover location for linqpad

Tags: q, linqpad

Where do the autorecover files get saved for linqpad?  I lost some queries, and like SSMS, I'm hoping the files are still there, but the autorecover is just not pulling them up for some reason when I start up linqpad.

Alternatively, does linqpad compile to a temporary location?  I could recover my work by decompiling the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQPad's autorecover location is `%temp%\LINQPad5`

Under there, there are subfolders prefixed with an underscore for each active session. Inside the subfolders is a file with a `.autosave` extension. The query assemblies are also stored in there.

Comment: Just had an update to a newer version of windows 10 and it has moved the temp folder from c:\windows\users\xxx\appdata\local to c:\windows.old\users\xxx\appdata\local. So I was able to recover my unsaved queries by moving the LinqPad5 back to the new temp folder.

Comment: This path didn't work for me, but the path in @svonidze 's answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946155/1724702

Answer (score 2):

Found my unsaved queries in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\LINQPad\Sessions\LINQPad6` grouped by session folders.